# Type Guard Typescript not inferring function rest parameters correctly

Tags: typescript, typeguards, rest-parameters

I have an example of Typescript with type guard and function rest parameters:

```js
interface BaseProps {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

type Props = BaseProps & (
  | {isAdmin: true, adminName: string} 
  | {isAdmin: false}
)


// Doesn't works
const myFn = ({isAdmin, ...rest}: Props) => {
  if(isAdmin === true) {
    rest.adminName; // Property 'adminName' does not exist on type '{ username: string; adminName: string; } | { username: string; }'.
  }
}

// It works
const myFn2 = (args: Props) => {
  if(args.isAdmin === true) {
    args.adminName;
  } 
}
```

What is wrong with the rest parameters and type guard?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPYAOGyA3gFDLICuWUIcAthAFzIZhSgDmZAvmWTABPAilyFiAXjSYc%20IsgBkyABQVkAH1LAMAQQAmDUKw5UIAGmRxDoAHKMWbDt17J1WkjoNGQreABssfgBKATIAenDkABE8CAwQAHIwZAB3PCgAawwyBDwQdmQGIQAxEGRpFU89GxBLADpGqHiwXlZxImCKgD5SdWAYFS9aislpUwgu8kpKZvZ66x97JgBudX5%20CKiASRT0rJy8gpTisoAmCtU4KC4MdvkMLsle6eQBlWvb%20uGfUfGoMxTdSUT4YBa1ZYQNaUVx8IA)

---

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**

I found the solution, using `Assert Functions` to resolve the issue.

```
declare function assertType<T>(val: unknown): asserts val is T;

const myFn = ({password, isAdmin, ...rest}: Props) => {

  if(isAdmin === true) {
    
    assertType<Omit<Props & {isAdmin: true}, keyof Props>>(rest);

    rest.adminName; // <=== HERE

    rest.username;

    // Should be error
    rest.password;
  }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPYAOGyA3gLABQyyArllCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNyVqBTBgDueKABN2nbiB6UAvpUpgAngRS5CxALxpMOfEWQAyZAApByAD6lgGAIKSmodlxoQANMjgvQAHLMbBxcvIrI1nYkDs6uIOzwADZYPixMAEbQQSwyYfLKFACUKhSlCHggnMhMagBiIMj6FiTCGGISkj6x-iA+AHSDUBCciuzaREVNAHykpdTAMBY98U26+h4QU+RU1JG71CLQYAAqGhAAPADyrmAXE8TmMU697lCeij4A1hBqeDDIB7TaYWYacIoCMoHZBgsD9PzxHIQPjIAD0qOQF3W+gAEgBRABKePme1h-To0EYLEh1mo6OQAGUABZ4GhJSTILLIaD4KC0mEjOFtDpSSHUQqFSj0xztY7ASrIOo0EAIMDyqpSjFMsBgIisdGiQ39dSaDAIbgEMBJODyfoSHioyR4BAYVFMm2SDJ4PBfVHDJIQQwAWhAeEgrpNI3NwEtQYAzEGAOz9bVMJIAYiOUDVlSDMGVqvVGEokggCGtw2Q+ZVOcaWdO5wuJxBADc4El2MqvqHRCAiux68Q20lkA5kCdIUA)

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Props` is

> { username: string, isAdmin: true, adminName: string } | { username: string, isAdmin: false }

When you assert the value of `isAdmin` on an object of type `Prop` (e.g. an `if` statement), typescript is then able to narrow down the actual type between `{ username: string, isAdmin: true, adminName: string }` and `{ username: string, isAdmin: false }`.

If you remove `isAdmin` by destructuring, the type of `rest` becomes

> { username: string, adminName: string } | { username: string }

The values `isAdmin` and `rest` become uncorrelated and the only way to narrow down the type of `rest` is to assert the presence of the `adminName` property.

Maybe you shouldnt use rest parameters for this specific case. You could also manually cast the `rest` variable inside the `if`.